# Using AngularJS custom field validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm using `$asyncValidators` to validate a field but would like it to trigger only when the field loses focus and not on every change. Is this possible or must I use something else than `$asyncValidators`?
Code example of using `$asyncValidators` (taken from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController))

```
ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
    var value = modelValue || viewValue;

    // Lookup user by username
    return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
        then(function resolved() {
            //username exists, this means validation fails
            return $q.reject('exists');
        }, function rejected() {
            //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
            return true;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the ngModelOptions directive to achieve that.

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

You can force your model to be "evaluated" only on some predefined events.
In your case, you want to evaluate it when you leave the field, so on the `blur` event.

[Official documentation of ngModelOptions directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Comment: Yes it works! Maybe I should read the documentation a bit closer :)